# pip pulling incorrect version?

Tags: python, pypi, semantic-versioning

In my private pypi I have two packages that I published:
`1.0.4+snapshot.2023.5.25.7.16.0` and `1.0.4`.
In `requirements.txt` I specify `package_name==1.0.4`, but `1.0.4+snapshot.2023.5.25.7.16.0` is pulled instead. Why is that?